# Schematic to connect ESP32 with SSR

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, gpio, esp32, solid-state-relay

I would like to connect the SSR (Fotek-40DA) with ESP32 and use PWM to control the phase angle thereby controlling the power going to the heater. The specs (Fotek-40DA) do mention the input voltage range to be 3-32V, however the internet seems to be split on this with many suggesting to use 5V instead of 3.3V. That is a possibility if not using PWM, however in this case we intent to use PWM and can't figure out a way. Any suggestions and guidance on this would be extremely helpful.

Please find the schematic..  [image]

Comment: Please provide links to the datasheets of all parts in question.  Also, please draw a schematic of how you think you'll hook up the SSR.

Comment: SSR will be connected to h6 in the schematic